# Updating Constraints/Frames After a View is Programmatically Removed from Superview (Autolayout)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, autolayout

I'm using Autolayout in IB. My screen layout looks like this:

```
+-----------------+
| +--+ +--+ +--+  |
| |  | |  | |  |  |
| |  | |  | |  |  |
| |1 | |2 | |3 |  |
| |  | |  | |  |  |
| |  | |  | |  |  |
| +--+ +--+ +--+  |
+-----------------+
```

My goal is to create a flexible dynamic view. Whenever one of those center boxes is removed from the view ([object removeFromSuperview]) I want the constraints to update, keeping a uniform space between all objects.

For example, upon removing the center object, the view should update as so:

```
+-----------------+
| +--+ +--+       |
| |  | |  |       |
| |  | |  |       |
| |1 | |3 |       |
| |  | |  |       |
| |  | |  |       |
| +--+ +--+       |
+-----------------+
```

Currently I have size constraints, bottom space constraints, and leading space constraints - all uniform.

After calling removeFromSuperview, I've tried calling layoutIfNeeded, updateConstraints, and more. No effect. The objects simply stay where they were before.

Is this even possible to accomplish?

Comment: as suggested by @rdelmar, I'm using an array of subviews that I'm programmatically adding to the superview, and programmatically configuring constraints. It works very well, and doesn't even require that much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have those 3 views, you can create a horizontal spacing constraint between 1 & 3. Edit it to give it the value you want after 2 is removed, and change its priority to less than 1000, like 900. So, 3 will have a spacing constraint to both 1 and 2, but the one to 2 will take precedence until view 2 is removed. If you have more than 3 views, it will get a bit more complicated, but you can use a similar method.

Comment: Hmmm...what about if the first view gets removed instead of the center? I have at least four views right now, probably more coming in the future.

Comment: @cdstamper, you would need 2 to have a lower priority constraint to the left edge to take care of the removing 1 case. As you get to 4 or more view, things will get complicated fast. I'll have to think if there's a better more general way to so this. Will you sometimes be deleting more than one of the views? Do we have to account for that possibility as well?

Comment: Yes, I'll sometimes be removing two or three items. A collection view would probably be appropriate but I'm not going to embed one into all my table view cells...

Comment: @cdstamper, I would not try to do this like I said in my answer then, I think it will get too complicated. I would keep an array of my views, and after a deletion, delete all the horizontal constraints, then add them back starting with one to the left edge for whatever view is the first one in your array, then making new ones from the 2nd to the first, 3rd to the 2nd, etc. If you do this in a loop it won't actually involve all that much code.

Comment: That's actually a really good solution. I'm going to go with this. Thanks @rdelmar !

Answer (score 2):

You probably have a constraint between views `2` and `3` for spacing.

When you remove view `2`, you will have to create a new constraint between view `1` and `3`.

If the number of views is truly dynamic and each one is a consistent size, you should probably be using a `UICollectionView` instead.

Comment: I would have assumed the constraints were 'left space to nearest object' not 'left space to object x', if that makes any sense. Seems like it shouldn't get deleted with the object...I'll give this a try. A collection view seemed too heavy, this is really just a small UI element inside of a UITableViewCell.